# Cordova iOS Video tag Local File Source

Tags: ios, cordova, video, html5-video, phonegap-build

I have problem playing local video on iOS on my Cordova based app. At the beginning I want to stress out that this problem is happening only when I'm using **WKWebView**, and if UiWebView is used, video plays fine. This is scenario I have:

-User comes to screen to which video url is passed

-Via FileTransfer I download it to phone and store it at desired location

-Using JS video is loaded to `<video>` tag and played.

Basically I'm doing everything as described in answer to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083023/video-tag-local-file-download-cordova-android).
The problem with UiWebView was that if relative path was set to src, video for some reason couldn't be loaded (no matter which combination I used), so this solution worked great for me, because it is based on this line of code:

```
entry.toURL()
```

This returns full path of the downloaded video which is great, at least for the UiWebView.

The problem for WkWebView is that  entry.toURL() returns smth. like this:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3A43AFB5-BEF6-4A0C-BBDB-FC7D2D98BEE9/Documents/videos/Dips.mp4
```

And WKWebView doesn't work with file:// protocol. Also, neither WKWebView  works wit relative paths :(

Can anyone help me to fix this ?

Comment: Make sure you have the `AllowInlineMediaPlayback` preference for iOS enabled in your `config.xml`. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#preference. Also, which plugin are you using to enable use of WKWebView?

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, yes, I have added that line, but unfortunatly  it didn't help me. I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546965/why-is-my-ios-app-rejecting-cdvfile-and-file-links

Comment: @daserge i believe this should help, but I cannot get it to work :/ so this is what i get as absolute url: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A313B954-55C5-49F1-801F-5AF519EA4E8E/Library/files/video/High-Knees.mp4`.
And these are combinations which I have tried (non of them worked):
`http://localhost:12344/Library/files/video/High-Knees.mp4`
`http://localhost:12344/video/High-Knees.mp4`
`http://localhost:12344/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A313B954-55C5-49F1-801F-5AF519EA4E8E/Library/files/video/High-Knees.mp4`

Comment: @hyperN If your are downloading the file and storing it in device, cant you just open the video using fileopener cordova plugin that lets you play the video in desired player?

Comment: @Gandhi, I'm not sure how this plugin is going to help me when I need to provide it with path to downloaded file ? I believe video tag is not problem but something with the path is not working properly, even though in Xcode I've confirmed everything was downloaded ok (and to right path), but when file was accessed it could not be found.

Comment: @hyperN Posted sample snippet which i have tried out in both android and iOS. It does work fine.

Comment: `http://localhost:12344/Documents/files/video/High-Knees.mp4`?

Comment: Yes, also I tried with Documents, Library, Document/NoCloud, Library/NoCloud ... nothing :(

Comment: @hyperN does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working today with the following but **only when deployed to my device in Release mode**. When deploying the app in Debug mode to my device it would not work.

- iOS 9.3.2
- Cordova 4.0.0 (iOS 3.8.0)
- Telerik WKWebView Polyfill 0.6.9

**Video list load method:**

```
var path = window.cordova.file.documentsDirectory, //iTunes File Sharing directory
    href = 'http://localhost:12344/Documents', //WKWebView default server url to documents
    list = [];
function fsSuccess(dir) {
    var reader = dir.createReader();
    reader.readEntries(function (entries) {
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            list.push({ name: entries[i].name, path: href + entries[i].fullPath });
        }
    });
}
function fsError(error) {
    console.log('error', error)
}
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, fsSuccess, fsError);
```

**Video list click handler:**

```
var video = $('#video')[0],
    source = $('#source');
function play(index) {
    source.attr('src', list[index].path);
    video.load();
    video.play();
}
```

**Video player markup:**

```
<video id="video" autoplay controls loop webkit-playsinline>
    <source id="source" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I was banging my head on my desk a la Ren Hoek while debugging until I attempted a release buid and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Sample snippet that uses cordova file opener plugin to open the download file from device.(Not tested in WKWebView though)

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var cdr;

if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
} else {
    // for iOS
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
}

function onError(e) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Error : Downloading Failed");
};

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    var entry = "";
    if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
        entry = fileSystem;
    } else {
        entry = fileSystem.root;
    }
    entry.getDirectory("Cordova", {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
};

function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
    cdr = dir;
    dir.getFile(filename, {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, gotFileEntry, errorHandler);
};

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    // URL in which the pdf is available
    var documentUrl = "http://localhost:8080/testapp/test.pdf";
    var uri = encodeURI(documentUrl);
    fileTransfer.download(uri, cdr.nativeURL + "test.pdf",
        function(entry) {
            // Logic to open file using file opener plugin
            openFile();
        },
        function(error) {
            navigator.notification.alert(ajaxErrorMsg);
        },
        false
    );
};

function openFile() {
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
        cdr.nativeURL + "test.pdf",
        "application/pdf", //mimetype
        {
            error: function(e) {
                navigator.notification.alert("Error Opening the File.Unsupported document format.");
            },
            success: function() {
                // success callback handler
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: I found like 5 bugs in this code ... and after fixing all of those it still doesn't work. Have you tested this specifically on WKWebView ?

Comment: @hyperN Have not tried in WKWebView. Will check and get back. But its so unfortunate that the answer was downvoted trying to provide a possible solution

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer, but I have spent more time fixing bugs in this code than adapting it to my needs only to find out that you have not read my question, in which I am stating in very first sentence that problem is only with WKWebView. Sorry, but I don't find this very helpful at all. Anyway at the and I wanted to give it one more chance and I've written whole thing from beginning using this plugin and plugin in the end worked but only useful thing I could do with it was to save video to "Photos" or share it not actually play the video which is useless for me.

Comment: @hyperN Do you mean to say that you got it working in WKWebview now using file and file opener plugin?

Comment: Yes, but not due to this code, and it still hasn't solve my problem

Comment: @hyperN If you have made it work, the file opener plugin is not prompting you to open the video in supported applications?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110397/discussion-between-gandhi-and-hypern).

Comment: @hyperN Was having a look at this link - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine related to this issue and its mentioned as "The AllowInlineMediaPlayback preference will not work because of this Apple bug." Looking further at the issue link - http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6673091526656000 it seems to be a bug in iOS9 and greater version. Does that mean your issue cant be resolved? Can you have a look

Comment: Thanks I'll look as soon as I can (but that may be tomorrow and get back to you)

Comment: @hyperN Fine.Please keep us posted

Comment: I took quick look, and noticed that problem is only with this preference, AllowInlineMediaPlayback ... and I'm not using it :) Also could you edit bit your answer (just edit anything) so I could upvpote your post ? I acted harshly and I was mistaken and I want to thank you for your help somehow. Please accept my apologies !

Comment: @hyperN Have updated the post to mention that its not tested in WKWebView yet.Also you need not apologize as I overlooked your problem. Will dig deep and let you know if I found anything on this. Cheers.

Comment: @hyperN Can you please check if any of these links are helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882834/wkwebview-not-loading-local-files-under-ios-8/28676439#28676439 https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/WKWebViewTips