# android cordova app: opening .pdf file stored in www

Tags: android, html, cordova, pdf

I am working with Cordova to build a hybrid app in webview.
All my links work fine as long as I switch from one html page to another.

But now I am trying to get android to present the user with a dialog to choose how to open a .pdf file (residing in the res folder of www -local file that comes with the app) with no success.
Here are my latest efforts (none of them does anything -at all)

```
<a href=" ../res/DOC140416-1.pdf" onclick="window.open(../res/DOC.pdf,_system); return false"> <span>my test 01</span></a>

<a window.open("../res/DOC.pdf", "_system"); >my test 02</a>

<a href="#" onclick="window.open(encodeURI('../res/DOC.pdf'), '_system')"> my test 03</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @Neeezhelp you gotta try out inappbrowser plugin or file opener plugin

Comment: Thanks,  but I want file to be opened in dedicated pdf file :-)

Comment: file to be opened in dedicated PDF file means???

Comment: Opened in Acrobat Reader for example, allowing user to handle the file por sharing, anotating, etc...

Comment: if you wanna open in acrobat reader, file opener plugin is the best fit that allows you to open PDF in application of your choice

Comment: I tried the plgin already, did not find how to make it work...The git info is very scant :-)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629515/cordova-ios-video-tag-local-file-source/36889829#36889829

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the question, which does mention fileopener (deprecated now) but no help as to making it work.

Comment: Why does the _system argument not work?

Comment: Cordova file opener2 plugin is very much active

Comment: True for version 2, I wish it were for me ;-)

Comment: not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean I wish it worked for me :-/

Comment: Cant help until you post the complete code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113831/discussion-between-needzhelp-and-gandhi).

Comment: Look at this [example](https://github.com/simonprickett/pdfjscordova), especially https://github.com/simonprickett/pdfjscordova/blob/1fdee0cb8e549c136063baf19a91bda38a00abac/www/js/index.js#L128

Comment: @Needzhelp This comment helped me open PDFs using fileOpener2 in Android. https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/28#issuecomment-218442994

If you need clarifications, please tell me.

Comment: Thanks, i'm i'investigating right away :-)

Comment: I looked at the page. I am not sure where and how Jaspostigo's code is to be used. Does he mean on top of what the others had used or as a standalone script fired by an onclick event...I would need to see the full thing I suppose... :-) –