# Link to local files (cdvfile://) on iOS PhoneGap 3.3

Tags: ios, cordova

To easily update my app, I copy the content of the www folder to the phone and then do a `window.location = workingDirectory.toURL() + "/index.html"`.

**EDIT** - note that this works until Phonegap 3.4, but not on 3.5 (nothing seems to be happening when I try to change the location). If instead of `toURL` I use `toNativeURL`, then it works also on 3.5. **Using `toNativeURL` also fixes the current issue on iOS**.

Copying all the files and opening the index works fine on both iOS and Android. The problem on iOS though is that there is absolutely no styling to the page, as if the links to the CSS files weren't working. Everything is working fine on Android.

My links are relative (eg `<link href="css/reseter.css" rel="stylesheet">`). Links to other pages or to scripts do work.

Here is the simplified main page I open:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="red">I should be red but I'm not!</div>
    <a href="page2.html">This correctly takes me to the other page.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
.red { color: red; }
```

main.js

```
alert("HELLO is correctly displayed");
```

I correctly get the `alert` (its title is `cdvfile://localhost/`) and I can also correctly go to `page2.html`. The only problem is with the styles.

If I open the page in Safari pointing to my computer, the style is correctly displayed.

I tried a few things, to no avail:

- Add `<base href="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/MyApp/">` in the `<head>`
- Update all my href and src to have the full cdvfile path (eg use `<link href="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/MyApp/css/reseter.css" rel="stylesheet">`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working in **PhoneGap 2.9** by using `fileSystem.root.fullPath`. On PhoneGap 3.3 it only return `/`. Is this a bug on PhoneGap 3.3 that when using cdvfile, everything seems to work except the CSS files?

I decided to **temporally use a relative path** to my app for iOS on PhoneGap 3.3: `../../Documents/MyApp/index.html`. I don't know if it's safe to use or not.

**EDIT** In **Phonegap 3.5** (I haven't tested in 3.3), using work `window.location = workingDirectory.toNativeURL() + "/index.html";` (ie **using `toNativeURL` instead of `toURL`**) works.

Comment: I've the same problem and i temporally included my css to html page using <style> tag.

If i run my app on Android it simply work using relative path like "css/style.css"

Now i want to include a new font but there is the same problem! Did you solved in another way?

Comment: For now I'm using that hack as it works and it's really easy to use. I'll have to test from time to time if new Phonegap versions fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link (the plugin was changed):
http://cordova.apache.org/news/2014/02/10/plugins-release.html

Comment: Indeed things changed in February but it still looks like a bug to me that everything works correctly on Android, and everything except the CSS works on iOS...

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6532 I'll try with Phonegap 3.4 and latest plugin to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I still have the same issue with Phonegap 3.4 and org.apache.cordova.file 1.0.1.

Comment: As is written somewhere there, use toURL or toNativeURL methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into [CB-6532](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6532).  I just put in a pull request for a fix  -- you can temporarily use my fork until it is accepted:

https://github.com/loufranco/cordova-plugin-file

To use it, do

```
  cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.file
  cordova plugin add https://github.com/loufranco/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

Remember to reverse it if the pull request is accepted.