# Phonegap iOS link to file from filesystem

Tags: ios, cordova, filesystems, href

I created Phonegap application that holds web pages in file system. When I open any of these web pages from filesystem, only chosen page is loaded, but related files (images, css etc.) not.

For example there is webpage in filesystem under path:

```
cdvfile://localhost/temporary/1/
```

In this directory there are files like: index.html, style.css, img/background.png etc.
When I open file index.html only this file is opened, but page has no styles and no images. These related files have relative path in index.html.

This situation is on iOS platform only. On Android platform and on google chrome all works. Why is that and can I fix it?

EDIT:

I just figured out that links and js loaded from file work. For example:

```
<a href="page_b.html">link</a>
```

opens right page. But css like:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
```

are broken.

EDIT:

Unfortunately, this is an open bug in cordova project: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6532

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22801512/276648

I ended up using a relative path (ie something like `../../Documents/MyApp/temporary/1/`) instead of the full path (ie `cdvfile://localhost/temporary/1/`) to fix the CSS issues in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into [CB-6532](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6532).  I just put in a pull request for a fix  -- you can temporarily use my fork until it is accepted:

https://github.com/loufranco/cordova-plugin-file

To use it, do

```
  cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.file
  cordova plugin add https://github.com/loufranco/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

Remember to reverse it if the pull request is accepted.