# com.2fdevs.videogular won't work in phonegap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, videogular

I cannot include videogular service in phonegap. If I uncommect 'com.2sdevs.videogular', the app doesn't work. Anyone else have this issue?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap',
                                 'ngResource',
                                 'ngRoute',
                                 //'com.2fdevs.videogular',
                                 'ui.calendar',
                                 'ui.utils',
                                 'ui.sortable',
                                 'ngStorage',
                                 'googlechart'],
                     function ($compileProvider) {
                     $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|webcal|mailto):/);
                     }
                     );
```

I am including the JS file in index.html :

```
<script src="vendor/videogular/0.3.0/app/scripts/com/2fdevs/videogular/videogular.js"></script>
```

The JS is in that directory.
Thanks in advance.

I know this doesn't offer a lot more information. If there is a better way to get console messages, please let me know. I tried to do develop from the Safari, but I can get the console up until the app loads in the simulator and I think this is happening during load.

Here is the system.log with com.2fdevs.videogular:
    Sep 14 10:44:41 Matts-MacBook-Pro.local AngGap[3254] :

```
Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines"
You could find it at the following address https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-   storage/ .
Sep 14 10:44:43 Matts-MacBook-Pro.local backboardd[96900] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: timed out   fence 9c03
Sep 14 10:44:43 Matts-MacBook-Pro.local backboardd[96900] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: updates  deferred for too long
Sep 14 10:44:44 Matts-MacBook-Pro.local AngGap[3254] <Warning>: Resetting plugins due to page load.
Sep 14 10:44:45 Matts-MacBook-Pro.local AngGap[3254] <Warning>: Finished load of:   file:///Users/matt/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/F11B5DC0-4490-43F6-8E5F-8FDBED320318/AngGap.app/www/index.html#/
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not too much to do to work with Videogular.

Maybe you could try the latest version (0.5.1). Also take a look to this threads, maybe are helpful for you.

- https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/issues/73
- [Cordova video / audio won't play from cdvfile:// urls after update to 3.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846046/cordova-video-audio-wont-play-from-cdvfile-urls-after-update-to-3-3-0)

It would be great if you have some logs of your app to see whats happening because it should be pretty easy to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, had to reset device from debugger (command-R) in Safari, as this was happening at load.
Get an error about SanitizeURI. So had to comment out ngSanitize from videogular.js:

```
angular.module("com.2fdevs.videogular", [/*"ngSanitize"*/])
```